# Posting a form to an iframe

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to submit my form to an iframe, but it does not work. It instead opens in a new tab. How can I do it? Thanks

```html
<form action="https://cp.payguru.com/" method="post" id="paymentData" target="FormFrame">
  @foreach (var item in data)
  {
    <input type="hidden" name="@item.Name" value="@item.Value" />
  }
  <hr/>
  <div class="text-center"><input type="submit" value="Devam Et" class="btn btn-primary" /></div>
</form>
<iframe id="FormFrame"></iframe>
```

Comment: What condition defines "not work"? Put additional code & details to help someone found your issue.

Comment: its opened another tab

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because when posting from a `form` to an `iframe`, the `target` of the form needs to be set to the `name` of the iframe, not the `id`:

```
<iframe id="FormFrame" name="FormFrame"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks its work fine

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped.